# onChange Search by using Select ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem implementing something like when user click the select tag option and then conversion pair will automatically find the data ask.

**EXAMPLE**

when **USER** select **GBPAUD** so the ask value will be 7429.4
now i slice the pairs GBPAUD turn as AUD using `var resultLast`. After that i create some string called `var conversionPairs = 'USD' + resultLast;`. So i console it i get `USDAUD`. My problem is how to make search filter on the `local.json` so i can get **USDAUD** ask value.

Here is my code.

I really appreciate for your help.

**React Code**

```
   class PipValueCalculator extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              selectValue: ''
            };
            this.selectAccountCurrency = this.selectAccountCurrency.bind(this);
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            fetch('local.json')
              .then(data => data.json())
              .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                  Values: data
                });
              });
          }

          renderCalculatorOption(Values){
            return (
              <option data-symbol={Values.Symbol} value={Values.ask}>{Values.Symbol}</option>
            );
          }

          selectAccountCurrency(e){
            console.log('target-value', e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-symbol'));
            var sliceLast = e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-symbol');
            var resultLast = sliceLast.slice(3,6);
            console.log(resultLast);
            var conversionPairs = 'USD' + resultLast;
            console.log(conversionPairs);

            this.setState({
              selectValue: e.target.value,
              currentValuePrice : e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-symbol')
            });

          }


          render() {
            if(!this.state.Values) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            return (
              <div>
               <FormGroup className="col-sm-12 col-md-4" controlId="formControlsSelect">
                <FormControl className="calculator-option" componentClass="select" placeholder="select" ref="tester" value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.selectAccountCurrency} >
                  <option value="select">Currency Pairs</option>
                  {this.state.Values && this.state.Values.map(this.renderCalculatorOption, this)}
                </FormControl>
              </FormGroup>
<div className="calculator-group text-left">
          <p className="calculator__text" >Current Conversion Price: {this.state.currentValuePrice}</p>
          <p className="calculator__text" >Ask Price: {this.state.selectValue}</p>
        </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default PipValueCalculator;
```

**Local.json**

```
[
   {
      "Symbol":"GBPAUD",
      "ask":7429.4
   },
   {
      "Symbol":"USDAUD",
      "ask":5705.0
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is an array, you can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object matching your selected symbol. It looks like this:

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
arr.find( num => num > 2 ) // returns 3
```

Basically, you give it a function that gets called for each item in the array to determine if it's the one you want. That function must return a truthy or falsey value for each item. The first item that returns true is what gets returned from `find()`.

To make that work with your code you'll want to change a few things:

```
// in the constructor
this.state = {
  selectValue: '',
  // set a default empty array value
  Values: []
}

// inside render, in <FormControl>
// just render the array directly and set the value to the symbol
// this simplifies things, since the symbol can find you the price
{
  this.state.Values.map( value =>
    <option value={value.Symbol}>
      {value.Symbol}
    </option>
  )
}

// in the event handler
// use the symbol value from the select menu to find the right object
// then pull the price from that object 
selectAccountCurrency(e) {
  const selectedOption = this.state.Values
    .find( value => value.Symbol === e.target.value )

  this.setState({
    selectValue: e.target.value,
    currentValuePrice: selectedOption
      ? selectedOption.ask
      : 0 // whatever your fallback is for the empty option
  })
}
```

You might also consider naming you state keys without capital letters. That makes them seem like components. Either `values` or `options` (like an option tag) would read much better than `Values`. The same goes for `Symbol`, especially considering that it's a reserved word now.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. ;)